# Degenerated Anderson Model Simulation

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations, computational-physics

I'm trying to simulate the degenerative Anderson model. So depending on an energy difference first orbital and afterwards spin magnetism occurs. First i try to solve an easier ansatz with a limitation of only two orbitals to $l_z = \pm 1$.
In this case i end up with a set of 4 equations:

$\Delta \tan^{-1} (1/\pi * n_{m \sigma}) = E_0-E_f+(U-J)n_{\overline{m}\sigma}+U(n_{1\overline{\sigma}}+n_{2\overline{\sigma}})$

Where here $\sigma$ is the direction of the spin of certain electron in the orbital $m$, here only $1,2$ and the overline always is the opposite. U is a Hubbard potential and $J$ an intraatomic exchange. 
So we gathered a self consistent set of non-linear equation and i want to find solution in terms of $n_{m \sigma}$ satisfying all 4 equations. I already did some simulation and were able to plot it on dependancy of the energy difference with respect to the fermi energy, which is my parameter. So i change it in a certain range and one finds magnetic solution for $E_0 < E_f$.

Is there a good method to solve such a problem with not too much calculation power? And in the end i want to play around with both potentials and see how the number of electron is changing for each situation.

Thanks for any advice,

/no

PS: i already asked a question concerning to my code i wrote in SO, but i was rethinking the method of mine for solving this problem. I did an iterative attempt and reformulated the equation for a root searching algorithm and varied the energy difference $E_0 - E_f$.  The programming stuff is on [ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269212/ipython-solve-set-of-self-consistent-equation) plus a result of one simualtion run.

Comment: I suggest you try asking this on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/